# Extract specific words in regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm struggling a little with a regular expression here.

I have a sentence like this: "what is the date of birth of John Smith". I would like to extract the keywords [date of birth] but I'm not sure how to do it since the word of is also present later in the sentence.

Thanks,
Gwendal

Comment: Why do you mean by `extract the keywords` ? - Just get the positions or something else

Comment: Do you mean the first occurrence of 'date of birth'?

Comment: @2012-EndoftheWorld, at the first instance I thought it's link to the answer ;) then realized its username :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to check the presence of the string `date of birth` then use the `String contains(CharSequence s)` method.

**Usage**

```
String str="what is the date of birth of John Smith";
str.contains("date of birth"); // Returns in Boolean whether the char sequence is present in s
```

If you want to know the first occurrence of the specified substring use `int indexOf(String str)` method

**Usage**

```
String str="what is the date of birth of John Smith";
str.indexOf("date of birth"); // Returns the first pos of occurence of the substring
```

Check this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for more information on String

Comment: I also think this is what he needs, but I wonder why he is trying to use regex if this is the case

Comment: Thanks guys.Sorry if it was unclear. I can't use the search for the words "date of birth" as it could be something else like what is the age of John Smth, what is the gender of John Smith...I want to extract anything that is after "the" and before the "of" (which would be the second 'of' in the case of "date of birth"

Comment: @user1881244 you have to make a list of keywords before searching. Like `date of birth` , `age` , `gender` and so on. Then you should do the searching. You can store the keywords in an array

Comment: @2012-end-of-the-world. Thanks, I was looking for something a little bit more dynamic as the list is virtually unknown (infinite). This is why I was using regex, but I can't get it to extract the words between **the** and **of**.

Comment: @user1881244 if you do not know all the keywords then I doubt how would you make the program understand to select which words , like in the case of `date of birth` as duplicate words can exist.

Comment: @2012-end-of-the-world Thanks, that's what I thought. I'll look at other methods.